# Why is Django LoginView login not working?

Tags: python, django

I made a login form using Django ready LoginVew class, but idk why it isnot working. Here is the code

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginform = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')
        loginform(request)
        return redirect('signup')
    loginform = AuthenticationForm(request)

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'loginform': loginform})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('signup/', include('signup.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="log-outside">
    <div class="log-inside">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ loginform }}
        <button type="subbmit">Log in</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "is not working" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What is happening?  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change `template_name` in `LoginView`, the easiest way is to make changes to `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='main/index.html',
    ), name='login'),
]
```

You can use the following settings in the `settings.py` file to redirect a user who is not logged in.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'Dashboard:index'
LOGIN_URL = 'Account:login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'Account:login'
```

Comment: but want to do that in my own view:(

Comment: you can't use generic views in the method base views. you can extend them.

Comment: do you mind sharing how that is supposed to be done